# RegExp to match sequence of optional characters

Tags: regex

I have strings of this kind (open and close decorators):

```
####--- foobar ---###
### -- foobar -- ###
####-- foobar ---##
--- foobar ---
### foobar ##
### foo - bar ##
```

I'm trying to:

1. test if a given string matches this pattern
2. strip these "decorations"

I tried with these two RegExp:

```
/-*\s*#*/g;
/#*\s*-*/g
```

But the problem is that those will match even zero characters.

How can I tell my RegExp to match only if at least two `##` or `--` are present in the sequence?

I need my RegExp to match the whole decorator obviously (`### ---`) not just part of it. So that I'm going to be able to strip them from the string, obtaining just the title in the middle (`foobar` or `foo - bar`)

Comment: You can use `/([#-])\1+/g`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava but it doesn't seem to match the whole "decorator", but just the first part of it (either `###` or `---`, not `### ---`)

Comment: Doing so it's going to match two groups, without matching the space in between

Comment: Actually my question asks how to 1. test the string matches the criteria, 2. strip the decorators (aka, matching the whole group). And I also clarified it few minutes ago to make it clear I want to match the whole decorator.

Comment: I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\s*([#-])\1+\s*/g
```

or use `[ \t]` instead of `\s` to match space or tab only:

```
[ \t]*([#-])\1+[ \t]*
```

and use same in `.replace` to remove decorators:

```
str = str.replace(/[ \t]*([#-])\1+[ \t]*/g, '');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0fuGWq/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `([#-])`: Match and group `#` or `-` in group #1
- `\1+`: `\1` is Backreference of what we captured in group #1. `\1+` we match 1+ character of same repeated character.